# Option from Autocomplete aren't getting removed in React MaterialUI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am beginner in ReactJS and currently working with Material UI `Autocomplete` component. I have a `data` object with keys as `table name` and `columns` as their value; an array of objects called `columnData`(is populated from values of `data`) with `field, ifSelected` as its attributes, and `field` attribute used to set the option label of `Autocomplete`(which are rendered as `Chip`). When an option is selected in `Autocomplete` dropdown then corresponding `ifSelected` attribute is set to `true`. However, problem comes when `columnData` object changes when a user selects different `table name` from `data` object and its corresponding value is assigned to `columnData`, in which previously selected option label isn't getting removed even when `ifSelected` attribute of all the option is `false`.

I went through `material-ui` docs [here](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/) and tried fixing it using `getOptionSelected` prop but faced issue with deletion of `chips`(i.e options) with that.

Following is my code:-

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Chip, TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import Autocomplete from "@material-ui/lab/Autocomplete";

export default class MultiSelect extends Component {
  state = {
    table: "",
    tableData: [],
    data: {
      table1: ["col1", "col2", "col3", "col4", "col5"],
      table2: ["cola", "colb", "colc", "cold", "cole"]
    },
    columnData: []
  };

  handleTableChange = (event, value) => {
    console.log("Table change value is ", value);
    if (this.state.data[value]) {
      let columnData = this.state.data[value].map((column) => ({
        field: column,
        ifSelected: false
      }));
      console.log("Table change value is ", columnData);
      this.setState({ table: value, columnData });
    }
  };

  handleColumnChange = (columns) => {
    let data = this.state.columnData;

    if (data && columns) {
      data.forEach((column) => (column.ifSelected = false));
      console.log("Columns are ", columns);
      for (let column of columns) {
        let index = data.findIndex((item) => item.field === column.field);
        console.log("index is ", index);
        if (index !== -1) data[index].ifSelected = true;
      }
      this.setState({ columnData: data });
    }
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    let tableData = Object.keys(this.state.data);
    this.setState({ tableData });
    this.handleTableChange("table1");
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <>
        <Autocomplete
          id="table"
          options={this.state.tableData}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField {...params} variant="outlined" margin="normal" />
          )}
          value={this.state.table}
          onChange={this.handleTableChange}
        />
        <Autocomplete
          disabled={!this.state.table}
          style={{ marginTop: "1rem" }}
          multiple
          disableCloseOnSelect
          limitTags={3}
          options={this.state.columnData}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option.field}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              style={{ fontWeight: "700" }}
              {...params}
              variant="outlined"
            />
          )}
          renderTags={(value, getTagProps) =>
            value.map((option, index) => (
              <Chip
                variant="outlined"
                key={option}
                label={option.field}
                {...getTagProps({ index })}
              />
            ))
          }
          onChange={(event, newValues) => this.handleColumnChange(newValues)}
        />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Would appreciate any hint. I have added demo [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-9kdb7?file=/demo.js)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix the issue by passing the `value` prop to select the columns with `ifSelected` set to `true`.

```
<Autocomplete
  value={this.state.columnData.filter((column) => column.ifSelected)}
  // other props
/>
```

[CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/autocomplete-forked-sspmi?file=/demo.js)